# Select first row after table is populated

Tags: java, selenium

I have this Angular SPA app which is displaying table rows after search:

```
<div class="ag-root-wrapper-body ag-layout-normal ag-focus-managed" ref="rootWrapperBody"><div class="ag-tab-guard ag-tab-guard-top" role="presentation" tabindex="0"></div>
                    <!--AG-GRID-COMP--><div class="ag-root ag-unselectable ag-layout-normal" role="grid" unselectable="on" ref="gridPanel" aria-rowcount="2" aria-colcount="8">
        <!--AG-HEADER-ROOT--><div class="ag-header ag-focus-managed ag-pivot-off" role="presentation" ref="headerRoot" unselectable="on" style="height: 26px; min-height: 26px;">
            <div class="ag-pinned-left-header ag-hidden" ref="ePinnedLeftHeader" role="presentation" style="width: 0px; max-width: 0px; min-width: 0px;"><div class="ag-header-row ag-header-row-column" role="row" aria-rowindex="1" style="top: 0px; height: 25px; width: 0px;"></div></div>
            <div class="ag-header-viewport" ref="eHeaderViewport" role="presentation">
                <div class="ag-header-container" ref="eHeaderContainer" role="rowgroup" style="width: 800px; transform: translateX(0px);"><div class="ag-header-row ag-header-row-column" role="row" aria-rowindex="1" style="top: 0px; height: 25px; width: 800px;"><div class="ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed ag-header-cell-sortable" role="columnheader" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-sort="none" aria-colindex="1" col-id="lookupCode" style="width: 200px; left: 0px;">
            <div ref="eResize" class="ag-header-cell-resize ag-hidden" role="presentation"></div>
            <!--AG-CHECKBOX--><div role="presentation" ref="cbSelectAll" class="ag-header-select-all ag-labeled ag-label-align-right ag-checkbox ag-input-field ag-hidden">
                <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-input-field-label ag-label ag-hidden ag-checkbox-label"></div>
                <div ref="eWrapper" class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-checkbox-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
                    <input ref="eInput" class="ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="ag-306-input" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Press Space to toggle all rows selection (unchecked)">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="ag-cell-label-container ag-header-cell-sorted-none">
            
            <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" unselectable="on">Serial Number</span>
                <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-filter-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
                <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-order ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span ref="eSortAsc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortDesc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-descending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortNone" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-none-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-none" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div></div><div class="ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed ag-header-cell-sortable" role="columnheader" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-sort="none" aria-colindex="6" col-id="materialName" style="width: 200px; left: 200px;">
            <div ref="eResize" class="ag-header-cell-resize ag-hidden" role="presentation"></div>
            <!--AG-CHECKBOX--><div role="presentation" ref="cbSelectAll" class="ag-header-select-all ag-labeled ag-label-align-right ag-checkbox ag-input-field ag-hidden">
                <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-input-field-label ag-label ag-hidden ag-checkbox-label"></div>
                <div ref="eWrapper" class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-checkbox-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
                    <input ref="eInput" class="ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="ag-309-input" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Press Space to toggle all rows selection (unchecked)">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="ag-cell-label-container ag-header-cell-sorted-none">
            
            <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" unselectable="on">Material</span>
                <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-filter-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
                <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-order ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span ref="eSortAsc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortDesc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-descending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortNone" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-none-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-none" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div></div><div class="ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed ag-header-cell-sortable" role="columnheader" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-sort="none" aria-colindex="7" col-id="lotLookupCode" style="width: 200px; left: 400px;">
            <div ref="eResize" class="ag-header-cell-resize ag-hidden" role="presentation"></div>
            <!--AG-CHECKBOX--><div role="presentation" ref="cbSelectAll" class="ag-header-select-all ag-labeled ag-label-align-right ag-checkbox ag-input-field ag-hidden">
                <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-input-field-label ag-label ag-hidden ag-checkbox-label"></div>
                <div ref="eWrapper" class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-checkbox-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
                    <input ref="eInput" class="ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="ag-312-input" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Press Space to toggle all rows selection (unchecked)">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="ag-cell-label-container ag-header-cell-sorted-none">
            
            <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" unselectable="on">Lot</span>
                <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-filter-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
                <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-order ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span ref="eSortAsc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortDesc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-descending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortNone" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-none-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-none" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div></div><div class="ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed ag-header-cell-sortable" role="columnheader" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-sort="none" aria-colindex="8" col-id="packagingName" style="width: 200px; left: 600px;">
            <div ref="eResize" class="ag-header-cell-resize ag-hidden" role="presentation"></div>
            <!--AG-CHECKBOX--><div role="presentation" ref="cbSelectAll" class="ag-header-select-all ag-labeled ag-label-align-right ag-checkbox ag-input-field ag-hidden">
                <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-input-field-label ag-label ag-hidden ag-checkbox-label"></div>
                <div ref="eWrapper" class="ag-wrapper ag-input-wrapper ag-checkbox-input-wrapper" role="presentation">
                    <input ref="eInput" class="ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="ag-336-input" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Press Space to toggle all rows selection (unchecked)">
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="ag-cell-label-container ag-header-cell-sorted-none">
            
            <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-label" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <span ref="eText" class="ag-header-cell-text" unselectable="on">Unit</span>
                <span ref="eFilter" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-filter-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-filter" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
                <span ref="eSortOrder" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-order ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span ref="eSortAsc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-ascending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortDesc" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-descending-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i></span>
                <span ref="eSortNone" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-label-icon ag-sort-none-icon ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ag-icon ag-icon-none" unselectable="on" role="presentation"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div></div></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-pinned-right-header ag-hidden" ref="ePinnedRightHeader" role="presentation" style="width: 0px; max-width: 0px; min-width: 0px;"><div class="ag-header-row ag-header-row-column" role="row" aria-rowindex="1" style="top: 0px; height: 25px; width: 0px;"></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-floating-top" ref="eTop" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="min-height: 0px; height: 0px; display: none; overflow-y: hidden;">
            <div class="ag-pinned-left-floating-top ag-hidden" ref="eLeftTop" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
            <div class="ag-floating-top-viewport" ref="eTopViewport" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <div class="ag-floating-top-container" ref="eTopContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="width: 800px; transform: translateX(0px);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-pinned-right-floating-top ag-hidden" ref="eRightTop" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
            <div class="ag-floating-top-full-width-container ag-hidden" ref="eTopFullWidthContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-body-viewport ag-layout-normal ag-row-no-animation" ref="eBodyViewport" role="presentation">
            <div class="ag-pinned-left-cols-container ag-hidden" ref="eLeftContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="height: 50px;"><div role="row" row-index="0" aria-rowindex="2" row-id="2" comp-id="342" class="ag-row ag-row-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-first ag-row-last ag-row-selected" aria-selected="true" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(0px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to deselect this row."></div></div>
            <div class="ag-center-cols-clipper" ref="eCenterColsClipper" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="height: 50px;">
                <div class="ag-center-cols-viewport" ref="eCenterViewport" role="presentation" style="height: calc(100% + 0px);">
                    <div class="ag-center-cols-container" ref="eCenterContainer" role="rowgroup" unselectable="on" style="width: 800px; height: 50px;"><div role="row" row-index="0" aria-rowindex="2" row-id="2" comp-id="342" class="ag-row ag-row-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-first ag-row-last ag-row-selected" aria-selected="true" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(0px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to deselect this row."><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="343" col-id="lookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 0px;  ">6673718</div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="6" comp-id="344" col-id="materialName" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 200px;  ">Material_66737</div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="7" comp-id="345" col-id="lotLookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value ag-cell-focus" style="width: 200px; left: 400px;  ">Material_66737-GLot</div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="8" comp-id="346" col-id="packagingName" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 600px;  ">BOX</div></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-pinned-right-cols-container ag-hidden" ref="eRightContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="height: 50px;"><div role="row" row-index="0" aria-rowindex="2" row-id="2" comp-id="342" class="ag-row ag-row-focus ag-row-even ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-first ag-row-last ag-row-selected" aria-selected="true" style="height: 50px; transform: translateY(0px); " aria-label="Press SPACE to deselect this row."></div></div>
            <div class="ag-full-width-container" ref="eFullWidthContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="height: 50px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-floating-bottom" ref="eBottom" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="min-height: 0px; height: 0px; display: none; overflow-y: hidden;">
            <div class="ag-pinned-left-floating-bottom ag-hidden" ref="eLeftBottom" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
            <div class="ag-floating-bottom-viewport" ref="eBottomViewport" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                <div class="ag-floating-bottom-container" ref="eBottomContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="width: 800px; transform: translateX(0px);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-pinned-right-floating-bottom ag-hidden" ref="eRightBottom" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
            <div class="ag-floating-bottom-full-width-container ag-hidden" ref="eBottomFullWidthContainer" role="presentation" unselectable="on"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ag-body-horizontal-scroll" ref="eHorizontalScrollBody" aria-hidden="true" style="height: 0px; max-height: 0px; min-height: 0px;">
            <div class="ag-horizontal-left-spacer ag-scroller-corner" ref="eHorizontalLeftSpacer" style="width: 0px; max-width: 0px; min-width: 0px;"></div>
            <div class="ag-body-horizontal-scroll-viewport" ref="eBodyHorizontalScrollViewport" style="height: 0px; max-height: 0px; min-height: 0px;">
                <div class="ag-body-horizontal-scroll-container" ref="eBodyHorizontalScrollContainer" style="width: 800px; height: 0px; max-height: 0px; min-height: 0px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ag-horizontal-right-spacer ag-scroller-corner" ref="eHorizontalRightSpacer" style="width: 0px; max-width: 0px; min-width: 0px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!--AG-OVERLAY-WRAPPER--><div class="ag-overlay ag-hidden" aria-hidden="true" ref="overlayWrapper">
            <div class="ag-overlay-panel">
                <div class="ag-overlay-wrapper ag-layout-normal ag-overlay-no-rows-wrapper" ref="eOverlayWrapper"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                    
                <div class="ag-tab-guard ag-tab-guard-bottom" role="presentation" tabindex="0"></div></div>
```

Do you know how I can implement a listener with Java and Selenium which waits for table row to be displayed and clicks in it? I tried something like this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:not(.ag-hidden) > .ag-row-first"));
element.click();
```

But it's not working. Can you guide me for appropriate solution?

Comment: "but it's not working" -- What IS happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically if you pay attention, you would see that this table is not build using `tr` and `td tags.` Basically it is a `div` with `attribute` `role="row"`

Also, to answer this part

```
waits for table row to be displayed
```

we have 2 ways.

1. Use `findElements` onto that particular web element.
2. Use Explicit waits.

**Code with Explicit waits :**

This xpath `//div[@role='row'][@row-index='0']/div` matches `4 nodes in HTML DOM`. But since you've mentioned that you wanna, `target and click` on `6673718`, using the mentioned xpath it would click on the `first element` and that represent the `6673718`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@role='row'][@row-index='0']/div"))).click();
```

**Code with FindElements :**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
List<WebElement> listElems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@role='row'][@row-index='0']/div"));
if (listElems.size() > 0 ) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@role='row'][@row-index='0']/div"))).click();
}
else {
    System.out.println("Either element is not present, or it's not rendered properly");
}
```

Comment: I tested the code but it's not working.

Comment: Is there any error )

Comment: element not found.

Comment: @PeterPenzov :  Is it possible to share URL and credentials to my email id `pandeyabhishek895@gmail.com`

Answer (score 3):

To wait for some condition to be true you can use those two:

```
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions
```

like this:

```
public static WebDriverWait waitSec(int sec) {
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, sec);
}

public static WebElement clickableByXpath(String xpath, int sec) {
    WebElement element = waitSec(sec).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpath)));
    return element;
}

public static WebElement clickableById(String id, int sec) {
    WebElement element = waitSec(sec).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(id)));
    return element;
}
```

See all expected conditions in https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html

To implement as listener you need second `WebDriver` instance listening on page where the first `WebDriver` instance operates. Not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Which element I have to wait into my code?

Comment: 'which waits for table row to be displayed' Inspect the row and get some locator. Just avoid absolute xpath -> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-difference-between-relative-and-absolute-xpath-in-selenium.

Comment: The html code displays this https://pasteboard.co/pdqXhLS1CLrq.png. Can you provide URL?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a system behind VPN. I need to click on this: `<div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="1" comp-id="378" col-id="lookupCode" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-auto-height ag-cell-value" style="width: 200px; left: 0px;  ">6673718</div>`

Comment: OK, there are two elements with `col-id="lookupCode"`. `<div class="ag-header-cell ag-focus-managed ag-header-cell-sortable" role="columnheader" unselectable="on" tabindex="-1" aria-sort="none" aria-colindex="1" col-id="lookupCode" style="width: 200px; left: 0px;">` and the second you want to wait for. They have different `role` value so relative xpath will be `//div[@col-id='lookupCode' and @role='gridcell']`

Comment: Just put the relative xpath to `clickableByXpath(String xpath, int sec)` and make it to `clickableByXpath("//div[@col-id='lookupCode' and @role='gridcell']", 10).click();`

Comment: Looks like the table row is not clickable. I have to use visibilityOfElementLocated?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and it should work, here is how it works.
We have created our own expected condition here, which will check for class named ag-hidden to be missing from the element. every time it finds a value "ag-hidden" in the class it will return false and again check after 500 milliseconds until the method returns true for next 20 seconds. Here you can change the timeout as per your wish.

You can write the code to work on the first row of the table after this statement.

You can go through the following link to understand further about custom [expected condition](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-add-custom-expectedconditions-for-selenium)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
          WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.ag-overlay"));
          String classes = table.getAttribute("class");
                if(classes.contains("ag-hidden"))
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: For some reason it's not working. Any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

In table, we might have more td values in the webpage, always we should wait for the all the elements to be presented in the webpage. **presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy**

```
By divCss = By.cssSelector("div:not(.ag-hidden) > .ag-row-first");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(divCss));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(divCss));
```